# How to select the ideal image size for any screen?

Tags: android-studio, imageview, android-imageview, image-size

I am trying to insert the images into the screen but when I insert some large image it gives the error of "too large bit image" and when I insert a small image like 400 x 400 pixels it gets blurred.
How to select the exact image size so that it looks good (not blurred).

**here is the code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity2">
     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:src="@drawable/non"
         android:scaleType="centerCrop">

     </ImageView>
```

Comment: show your code, to get better help

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am running code in "Nexus 9". I have created an imageView and want to place an image in it. When I set scale-type as "Centercrop" it gets blurred. And when I use any other property like "Center/ Centerfit" it does not cover the whole screen.  So can guide me on how can I select the image size properly if I want to cover the whole screen what should be the size of the image (height and width).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a vector image or use different sizes of your raster image for each dpi.

I would suggest going for vector if you can because it's simpler & lighter but if you cant use a vector image, [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) will guide you.